# why original doubly linked is modified when i reverse using this method?

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to reverse a doubly linked list using iterative approach and i'm struck on the part where my original list is being modified even though i'm not using a pointer to pointer style modification of original list.

This is the reverse function i am using, `head` is a local variable declared in main
like `Node* head = NULL;` and is already populated with a set of values.

```
Node* reverse_iterative(Node* head)
{
    if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return head;

    Node *prev, *current=head, *temp;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        current->prev = current->next;
        current->next = temp;
        temp = current;
        current = current->prev;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

This is how i used this in main :

```
Node* rev = NULL;
rev = reverse_iterative(head);
```

Here is the output i got:

```
original list: 15 <=>25 <=>35 <=>45 <=>55 <=>65 <=>75 <=>
making the list actually reverse: 75 <=>65 <=>55 <=>45 <=>35 <=>25 <=>15 <=>
after reversing, the original list now: 15 <=>
```

I couldn't get the part where my original head node was being modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at your while-loop, and consider the following statement *on the initial iteration of the loop*:

```
current->next = temp;
```

What is in `temp` at the time of this assignment? Exposing more of the code, we have:

```
Node *prev, *current=head, *temp;
while(current != NULL)
{
    current->prev = current->next;
    current->next = temp;
    temp = current;
    current = current->prev;
}
```

Note that temp is uninitialized and thus an undefined pointer value. Your original head-ptr *next* ptr is being reset to garbage held in the uninitialized temp.

Fix this by doing the following:

```
Node *current=head, *temp=NULL;
while(current != NULL)
{
    temp = current->prev;
    current->prev = current->next;
    current->next = temp;
    temp = current;
    current = current->prev;
}
```

I've not had a chance to test it, but that should get you closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: i've changed the code including your changes but that doesn't really change anything. 
if i call `reverse_iterative(head)` any changes being made to `head` inside the function shouldn't really effect the head pointer of main right ?

Comment: @Abhilash They will not effect the head pointer, but they *will* effect the node it *points* to. That node is now at the *tail* of the list. you should be setting your head pointer to be the result of your reverse function. When you reverse the list, the new head pointer should be set to the new head (which used to be the tail). Without that your old head pointer will reference the *last* node in the list. Try `head = reverse_iterative(head);` to see what I mean.

Comment: @Abhilash if you don't want the original list modified you can either (a) make a copy and reverse that, or (b) reverse it *again* after dumping the reversed content. I.e. run `head = reverse_iterative(head);` a second time.

Comment: thanks that helped. but is there any better to not modify the original list and yet achieve a reversed list, apart from making a copy or doing it twice ?

Comment: @Abhilash Please clarify. Is the purpose of your reverse function to *reverse* the list, or make a reverse *copy* of the list. The latter will be easy enough. Just make a copy of the list, then reverse the copy. You'll have two lists, one backward of the other.

Comment: the purpose was to make a reverse copy. i'm going with using a copy to reverse it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want your original list to be modified at all.

But the loop modifies the original element. For example, current starts out pointing to the head element and you then modify its next and prev. This means the original head element is now modified.

Comment: Yes, I don't want my original list to be modified, is there any way i can do it with out actually making a copy or doing the reversal twice ?

Comment: Not really, no. If what you want is a list where the order is reversed, then you cannot reuse the old elements. You need separate elements if they are to point in opposite directions.